# Precise repeated function calls using Python for Windows

Tags: python, windows, performance, timer, timing

I am using python for windows. My goal is to call a function at the rate of 50 hz or every 20 ms. I have tried to use threading.timer objects, but are not accurate enough (+- 16 ms accuracy). I need something closer to 1 ms accuracy. Are there any other solutions? It isn't viable for me to switch to a linux environment for development.

Comment: You probably shouldn't use Python if 1ms precision matters to you.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the 2-minute [tour]. 
Moreover, open [Help] and read at least [ask]. Then, [edit] your question to provide a [mcve]. 
Questions that only ask for code are too broad and are likely to be [put on hold or closed](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions).